# Roambi ES4 and mysql can't connect

Tags: mysql

I am installing Roambi ES4 on a mac os x lion 10.7

After a lot of steps I get to connect to the roambi app with apache tomcat but I get this message.

Database Connection Error

A failure occurred connecting to the database. Please ensure a database exists for the given host and name of the connection string or correct the connection string in the "db" entry in the configuration file located at:
/Users/jorgediaz/.roambi/config.json

I installed the mysql and created a database but I don't have any directory called .rombi neither a file called  config.json

What can I do ?

Answer (score 6):

Please Check the  /Users/jorgediaz/.roambi/config.json file contains the connection string of mysql.

for example:

```
{"roambi-data":"0.2.0","db":"mysql://localhost/roambi?user=root&password=XXXXX","setup_complete":true}
```

If it is not there, Please restart your roambi server. Then Try again.